# How to move a dialog " correctly " angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material

I think i am not moving my pop-up correctly as you can see on the picture.

[Two dialog instead of one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZaM9.png)

How to handle this in angular?

EDIT : if you take a look closer to the picture i sent, there are one pop-up in the center, and there are one too at the bottom (in red). And i woud like that the one at the bottom disappears.

To display the pop-up, i am using this code : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

The only difference is the css : 
[my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6417c.png)

Comment: Hi, please take a look at this article. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Then update your question accordingly

Comment: What do you want to do? Explain what is wrong with this pop-up

Comment: Hey @Narm, just found out you can write `[ask]` as a shortcut to write this : [ask]. You can also try `[mcve]` to see what it does !

Comment: @Powkachu if you take a look closer to the picture i sent, there are one pop-up in the center, and there are one too at the bottom. And i woud like that the one at the bottom disappears

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the shortcut! @trichetriche

Comment: @Mazetarabu Oh ok, I see. But with the few information you gave us, we can't help. Can you show us the code you're using to display the pop-up?

Comment: @Powkachu To display the pop-up, i am using the exact same code introcuced here https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples
The only difference is in the css ( i updated my post to show you the css i am using )

Comment: If you remove your CSS, is it working? It seems this CSS doesn't apply to your dialog.

Comment: @Powkachu yeah it is working but it is showing the pop-up at the bottom, but I need it to be displayed at the middle ( as in the first picture)

Comment: I thought you were saying that the CSS created the bug. So the bottom div is displaying when the dialog are opened? That's weird, I'm trying to reproduce this...

Comment: @Powkachu By removing the css, i get this : https://puu.sh/zNb0d/d245888dd2.png
and i need the pop-up to be displayed in the middle :/

Comment: This is really not what you should have if you used the same code as the one on material's site. Did you include a theme to your project? Like step 4 here: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: @Powkachu I got nothing in styles.css

Comment: Are you using angular-cli? If you are, put @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in your style.css. If not, put <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet"> in your index.html. Then test again.

Comment: Almost perfect ! It removed the div at the bottom, it just added something strange at the bottom of my pop-up as you can see here : https://puu.sh/zNbqd/7ccd7d267d.png

this thing under the pop up : https://puu.sh/zNbsX/6371f6b866.png

Comment: Yes it's better! Did you remove your custom CSS? Are you opening multiple dialogs?

Comment: @Powkachu Oh well don't bother, i removed my css and everything is correct now ! Thanks you for you help, i love you ahah ! https://puu.sh/zNbVO/35f1ec6ac1.png

Comment: Yeeees de rien! ;) I will write an answer then!

Comment: Yes ! 
How can i contact you?

Comment: @Mazetarabu Contact me? I wrote an answer that you can validate, thanks :)

Comment: @Powkachu oh well there are no private message on stackoverflow, i didn't know, hmm, thank you still !

Comment: @Mazetarabu Yeah there is no private message... happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you didn't include a theme to your project.

Are you using angular-cli?

If you are, put
`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` in `style.css`.

If not, put `<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">` in `index.html`.

Then don't forget to remove your custom CSS!

Check step 4 here: [material.angular.io/guide/getting-started](http://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

This example can maybe help you first one:

```
this.dialog = this.dialog.open(Dialog1, {
            width: '100px',
            height: '1000px'
        });
        this.dialog.updatePosition({ top: '20px', left: '20px' });
this.dialog.afterClosed().subscribe((result: any) => {
  this.dialog2.close();
})
```

Second one 130 pixel to the left:

```
this.dialog2 = this.dialog2.open(Dialog2, {
            width: '100px',
            height: '1000px'
        });
        this.dialog2.updatePosition({ top: '20px', left: '130px' });
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer but it doesn't make the div disappears :
https://puu.sh/zNb8u/bc6aa55cf8.png